# how to change injection target to create treemap in jit infovis toolkit?

Tags: javascript, infovis

I need to create 2 squarified treemaps in one web page. I used jit infovis toolkit to help  create this treemap. is it possible to create treemaps not using div with id "infovis"?cause when i change the id of div into something else like "test" for example, it cause an error treemap doesn't work. I also already change the "inject into" property in jit javascript function that used to create treemap . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

In the standard examples of InfoVis, the div "infovis" is contained in the "center-container".  The html page generally includes a css file base.css. This file applies certain rules to both "infovis" and "center-container".

```
#infovis {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

And for center-container..

```
#center-container {
  width:600px;
  left:200px;
  background-color:#1a1a1a;
  color:#ccc;
}
```

You can check this in html file which renders the visualization. 
You should make sure that the div in which you want to inject the visualization, is applied same/similar rules.
You may also have to do some more changes in your html file and the css file, to make sure that you have a proper hierarchy of divs and all rules of base.css are applied properly to them.
This is all I can say without looking at your html file and your code.

Comment: thanks for the answer..it works now..yesterday i was careless the style and the div id was not match. after read your comment i realize it.lol.. thx..